# Django - invalid literal for int() with base 10: ',' when passing an array

Tags: python, django

I have the following script that passes a jQuery array in the url:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("#continue").click(function() {
            var selected = $("#meds").bootgrid("getSelectedRows");
            var url = "{% url 'meds:prescription' 'test' %}";
            url = url.replace('test', selected);
            window.location = url;
        });
    });
```

and the following view:

```
class PrescriptionView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'meds/prescription.html'
    context_object_name = 'meds'
    model = Medicament

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Medicament.objects.filter(id__in=self.kwargs['selected'])
```

The selected array looks something like `[3, 4]` and the url passed looks like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/prescription/3,4/`

I keep getting the error :

```
ValueError at /prescription/3,4/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ','
```

I just assumed that the array passed will be treated as a python list so I used `id__in` in the filter so I can compare the ids to the items of the list/array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`id__in` is expecting an array](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#in). 
What you are passing it is a string. Under the hood, it is trying to access the individual elements of the array in `int` format

You can do something like this:

```
ids = map(int, self.kwargs['selected'].split(","))
return Medicament.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

Basically, you are splitting on the delimiter, and creating an array of  ids.

Demo:

```
>>> x = "3,4"
>>> map(int, x.split(","))
[3, 4]
>>>
```